# React-Native app crashes immediately on android device, but works fine on simulator

Tags: react-native

It used to work fine on both mobile and simulator for 2 weeks from initializing the project, but from yesterday it only runs fine in android simulator but not the physical device. it crashes immediately and no logs are showing up in the console. it's the ordinary successful logs.

It works fine in the android device ONLY IF I TURN ON THE DEBUGGER!

I even created a new react-native project and copy-pasted the code I wrote into it, but the result was the same.

EDIT: This is the error I get:
[image]

Comment: This sounds like a race condition in your code. Using the debugger slows things down enough that the race condition doesn't happen.  I'd suggest creating a new project and making sure that works without modification, then gradually re-introduce your code bit by bit until you find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was a problem with some of my components that used an opacity